# Should the authorities on the token storage be updated when refreshing a token?

Tags: kotlin, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-authorization-server

I'm implementing role-based Jwt which includes authorities attribute inside of Jwt claims. Currently, I use Jwt customizer for extracting authentication object from the context and put it inside of Jwt claims like this. The problem is that, the authorities on the **JwtEncodingContext** won't be changed as it was stored only for the first time when the token has been issued.

```
 @Bean
 fun jwtCustomizer(): OAuth2TokenCustomizer<JwtEncodingContext> {
   return OAuth2TokenCustomizer { context: JwtEncodingContext ->
     val principal: Authentication = context.getPrincipal() // <-- this won't change 
     val user: UserDetailsImpl = principal.principal as UserDetailsImpl
     context.claims.claim("userId", user.getUserId())
     context.claims.claim("authorities", user.getAuthorities())
   }
 }
```

However, authorities of a user can be changed regularly, for example the authorities of a user changed from "ADMIN" to "USER" but since the **JwtEncodingContext** won't be changed so he still got an authority of "ADMIN" whenever he refreshes a token. So I'm not quite sure how to properly handle this, one thing that I can think of is that to force a user to re-login by revoking his token, but this solution probably gives a user really bad experiences due to the authorities can be changed regularly in my system. or maybe a little bit of a dirty solution is that to query the data from user details instead and put it inside of claims like this.

```
 @Bean
 fun jwtCustomizer(): OAuth2TokenCustomizer<JwtEncodingContext> {
   return OAuth2TokenCustomizer { context: JwtEncodingContext ->
     val principal: Authentication = context.getPrincipal() // <-- this won't change 
     val user: UserDetailsImpl = userDetailsRepository.findById(principal.getUserId())
     context.claims.claim("userId", user.getUserId())
     context.claims.claim("authorities", user.getAuthorities())
   }
 }
```

Any ideas how to handle this?

Comment: Are you asking "What is the proper way...?" I'm not sure that question will have an answer because it depends heavily on your use case. However, the way you've already identified could be a completely fine solution. Why do you feel this is a "dirty solution"? Does it not work for some reason? If so, please share. Also, what is the requirement for when changes to an admin's authorities should be reflected in the admin's actual access to resources in the system (e.g. how long is it allowed to take before it MUST take effect)?

Comment: @SteveRiesenberg Thanks for your response,  I feel like my solution is dirty as I am implementing my own security solution instead of utilizing the built-in components provided by Spring. In regards to the second question, the revocation of access tokens needs to take immediate effect. However, since I am using JWT, it is currently not possible to revoke an access token, and I am still looking for a way to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

The solution you outlined is one possible option, and it seems to me like a good start. Discussing in comments, I’d disagree that it is a “dirty” solution because you *are* actually using built-in components, namely the `OAuth2TokenCustomizer` and `UserDetailsService`. The built-in components in Spring Security are designed to allow you to integrate your authorization rules and requirements into the framework, which you are attempting to do. If you have a working solution for doing that, I would say that you have something to build on, and you can always improve it later or experiment with other ways if needed.

Another option would be to only include a `roles` claim (e.g. `"roles": ["ROLE_ADMIN"]`) in the access token, and perform the authority mapping in the resource server. This has the benefit of always being up to date, but the downside of scalability as it requires many resource servers to query the database where role to authority mappings are stored. If this is of interest, you would use a [`JwtGrantedAuthoritiesMapper`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/jwt.html#oauth2resourceserver-jwt-authorization-extraction) from `spring-security-oauth2-resource-server` on the resource server side.

I would also recommend opaque tokens instead of JWTs if immediate revocation is needed. [Similar support exists](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/opaque-token.html#oauth2resourceserver-opaque-authorization-extraction) if using opaque tokens instead, though it would be better to customize claims on the authz server in this case.